# Recursive Function Not Adding Items to ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I am trying to add an array of arrays to an ArrayList in Java. Only the last iteration of recursion is added to the ArrayList multiple times. I have the following Java class:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {
    ArrayList<int[][]> result;
    int[][] part;

    public Test() {
        result = new ArrayList<int[][]>();
        part = new int[2][2];
    }

    public void fill(int i) {
        if(i > 0) {
            part[0][0] = i;
            result.add(part);
            i--;
            fill(i);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.fill(4);

        for(int l = 0; l < test.result.size() - 1; l++) {
            for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                    System.out.print(test.result.get(l)[i][j] + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println("-----");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get the following result:

```
1 0 
0 0 
-----
1 0 
0 0 
-----
1 0 
0 0 
-----
```

Where I would expect:

```
3 0 
0 0 
-----
2 0 
0 0 
-----
1 0 
0 0 
-----
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you keep adding the same object `part` three times. The last update "sticks", while the prior ones get written over.

Moving array initialization into the body of your recursive method would fix this problem:

```
public void fill(int i) {
    if(i > 0) {
        int[][] part = new int[2][2];
        part[0][0] = i;
        result.add(part);
        i--;
        fill(i);
    }
}
```

Also remove the declaration of `part` from the `Test` class, because it is no longer in use.

Comment: How would you solve this problem if the part array needs to be accessed by other methods in the class?

Comment: @Dynamic There is no one "part", there's three in your example; could be even more. `result` has all of them, you can access any of the arrays as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

The `fill` method takes the array, set it's value at `[0][0]` to `i` and adds it to the list.

Then, it takes **the same** array(actually a reference to that array), overwrites it's value at `[0][0]` to `i` and adds it to the list.

So, you've added the same array multiple times but you have overwritten the first value in it.

​

[**Note**]

The attributes of your `Test` class are package private. I recommand you to set the visibility to `private` if there is no reason to do anything else.